# Align circles and text made with css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I made this layout but I can't find a way to align the circles and the text on the same line. As you can see in the first picture there's a problem both with circles and text. I'd like to achive the result you see in the 2nd picture.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.cell {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell:before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 0.5px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.circle img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  text-align: start;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle" style="background-image:url('https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/655f74e74d3b88cc9d367ba8cccd79680c3837a84a547f9e03b6f39981f424e0/3.png');"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Chiara Bersani <br> Marta Montanini</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: My Result]

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to remove your manual line breaks `<br>`. Once you do this, the text can wrap automatically without having odd breaks at specific breaking points. If you want to force a line break, use horizontal `padding` on `.caption h3`.

Once you do this, just use `align-items: self-start;` on `.grid`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: self-start;
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.cell {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell:before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 0.5px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}

.circle img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}


.caption h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.inner {
  text-align: start;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle" style="background-image:url('https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/655f74e74d3b88cc9d367ba8cccd79680c3837a84a547f9e03b6f39981f424e0/3.png');"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Chiara Bersani Marta Montanini</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle" style="background-image:url('https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/655f74e74d3b88cc9d367ba8cccd79680c3837a84a547f9e03b6f39981f424e0/3.png');"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Chiara Bersani Longer TEXT...........................</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle" style="background-image:url('https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/655f74e74d3b88cc9d367ba8cccd79680c3837a84a547f9e03b6f39981f424e0/3.png');"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Chiara Bersani Marta Montanini more text lorem foo</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```